# ddply summarize count based on string

Tags: r, count, plyr

My dataframe looks like this:

```
   userid                           Worktype  dwelltime
1 ABENAVI  Check Hazmat label Msg for carton  0.7666667
2 ARMITAJ  Check Hazmat label Msg for carton  0.3333333
3 ARMITAJ  Check Hazmat label Msg for carton  0.4166667
4 ARMITAJ         scanned to wrong sort rule  0.6500000
5 ARMITAJ         scanned to wrong sort rule  0.4666667
6 ARMITAJ  Check Hazmat label Msg for carton  0.4666667
7 ARMITAJ  Check Hazmat label Msg for carton 12.2333333
8 ARMITAJ  Check Hazmat label Msg for carton  4.5000000
```

I want to get the number of times each `userid` has `"scanned wrong sort rule"` as their `worktype`.

My result would look like

```
userid    Worktype  Count
ABENAVI   Scanned to wrong sort rule       2
Nithin    Scanned to wrong sortrule        0
```

I have written this code, which has been giving me an error

> "Error in ifelse(x[, "rf_log2$Worktype"] == "scanned to wrong sort rule",  :    unused argument (0)"

My code is:

```
quality <- ddply(rf_log2, .(userid), function(x) c(
              rules <- sum(ifelse(x[ ,"Worktype"] == "scanned to wrong sort rule", x[,"Worktype"],1,0), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a vector checking whether df$Worktype is equal to `"scanned to wrong sort rule"` and then use `table` to get the counts per `userid`:

```
df$check <- (df$Worktype == "scanned to wrong sort rule")
table(df[, c(1,4)])[, 2]
# ABENAVI ARMITAJ 
#       0       2
```